# How to properly model a One To Two relationship with EF7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

My object model requires a 1 to 2 relation between two tables and should ideally be able to be cascade deleted.

**What I'm trying to represent:**

A record (which, among other things, contains a property "Side", left or right) can belong to one or no record group. A record group is mandatorily composed of two records, one per side.

Deleting a record should delete the group it is part of as well.

**What I've tried to far:**

-> What EF migrations add command generated:

***Record***

| Side | RecordGroupId (fkey) |

***RecordGroup***

| ID | LeftRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete restrict) | RightRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete restrict) |

=> Works in so far that whenever I want to delete a record, I have to delete the group beforehand code side.

-> What I tought should work by just changing deletion behavior:

***Record***

| Side | RecordGroupId (fkey, *on delete set null*) |

***RecordGroup***

| ID | LeftRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) | RightRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) |

=> Creates a circular dependency whenever I try do delete either object.

-> Me trying to get rid of the reference group reference in the record table as an attempt to eliminate the circular dependancy:

***Record***

| Side |

***RecordGroup***

| ID | LeftRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) | RightRecordingId (not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) |

=> I then can't figure out how to include the recording group when building the record objects on context building.

-> Me trying to create a composite key as another attempt to mitigate my previous issues:

***Record***

| Side |

***RecordGroup***

LeftRecordingId (composite key, not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) | RightRecordingId (composite key, not null, fkey, on delete *cascade*) |

=> EF add migration command insists on having both record group key columns in my record table.

Is there a best practice to to build a 1 to 2 relationship with EF or should I frankenstein some raw sql into it?

Comment: Can you correctly model this behaviour in SQL directly? If yes, then build it up and use database first to find out how it should look in EF. That's my approach, whenever I'm stuck on how to write it in EF, but know how to model it in SQL.

Comment: There's no way to model a 1:2 relationship in a relational database. What you have is two 1:1 relationships. Cascading is always from parent to child (where child is the record with an FK) and (in SQL Server) there can't be multiple/circular cascade paths. These are the non-negotiables you have to abide. In this model that means that only one relationship can be cascading.